# J.S. Bach: March in C?

Tags: sheet-music, j-s-bach

I found a copy of the notes to "March in C" by J.S. Bach, see image attached. I’d like to learn more about it, but surprisingly, I can't find information or recordings online.

Can anyone here point to information or a recording of this piece? Is it known under a different name?

[image: March in C by J.S. Bach]

Comment: Do you have the full score that includes the string quartet parts? If yes, post the first few measures in the chat room. Just know, questions of identification are off-topic here on the main site. But there are a number of knowledgable Bachians here who might be able to help. This would be a perfectly fine chat question.

Comment: Stylistically I would suspect that it was composed by one of Bach's children, perhaps at some point attributed to J.S.  Many false attributions to J.S. are to be found in the household music books, but I don't recognize this from those.  Still, searching Bach's sons' work lists might help find it.

Comment: Why do you cut of the names, publication info that's probably at the bottom of page, not mention any other publication info on other pages, etc. etc. when asking other to get more info? Right from the start I'm trying to fill in those blanks about the pages you already have.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's from this book: "Chamber Music For Guitar And Strings" (1975), by Fred Nance and Mary Ann Godla (see https://kjos.com/chamber-music-for-guitar-and-strings.html). I only have a copy of the page, which doesn't have more info.

Comment: imslp lists one C major march attributed to carl phillip emmanuel bach, but sadly i could not find any recordings.